# How do i create a global unique error id? C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a bunch of errors. each specific to its own class and module. Then i would like to attach the id to an exception so when my msg change the id is still the same. How do i create this list of errors without maintaining a large global enum ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Divide the unsigned 32-bit hexadecimal number range up as a hierarchy:

```
0xMMCCCEEE
```

where:

- MM is module ID
- CCC is class ID
- EEE is error ID

Then you can have 0 to 0xFF (256) modules, and 0 to 0xFFF (4096) each of classes and errors, and you only have to ensure that each error is unique to its class, and each class is unique to its module, so you don't have to keep all error messages in a single giant table.

Example:

```
0x0401D00A
```

That's module 04, class 01D, error 00A.

Comment: Why would you care about assigning unique identifiers to error messages if you weren't going to keep all error messages in a single giant table?

Comment: I recommend an algorithm which condenses the current date, time and programmer name into an alpha numeric string. This way you are not limited to a field length and you will never run out of id's.

Answer (score 7):

Generate a GUID for each error.

Answer (score 1):

What's the purpose of having a unique identifier for each error?  Any exception that your code throws already has information that uniquely identifies it, i.e. the type of exception and the module name and line of code that threw it.  You don't need to assign an ID to an exception to know that it's not the same exception as one with a different type, or module, or line.

Generally speaking, the need to assign a unique ID to an entity emanates from the need to keep other information about that entity in some kind of durable store.  What are the characteristics of that durable store?  Those requirements almost certainly are going to provide the basis for evaluating the fitness of any particular ID scheme you come up with.  What are they?

Comment: The most common reason is so that errors can be quoted in communication with users, tech. support records, etc. IBM followed this approach religiously for decades.

Comment: Collapsing a long-ish piece of information down to a short identifier has a value that can be measured quite easily by comparing the space required by the two descriptions. This is why http://tinyurl.com/ exists.

Comment: You start appreciate it when you have your application localized in a dozen different languages. Say a Chinese customer sends you a bug report with attached screenshot of an error messagebox - in Chinese, naturally. If it has an error code, you just look it up and know what's it about. If it doesn't, you have to find someone who knows Chinese...

Comment: Right, I wasn't questioning the need for some kind of identification scheme.  What I'm saying is that some specific use cases for the identifier - in the original poster's specific context - would help in determining what the best scheme might be.  Without them, it's hard to tell whether one approach is better than another.

Answer (score 1):

```
Guid.CreateGuid();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a naive idea that every possible "error" can be assigned a point in "error space". Consider a simple example, where a method throws a particular error (I'll be courteous and say "throws", though in context, it used to be "returns"):

```
public void MyMethod() {
    // ...
    throw new ErrorException(ErrorCodes.MyMethodError1); // Or something
}
```

Perhaps this method is only called from one place in Release 1. That means it's possible in that release to document that error code MyMethodError1 means a particular thing.

In the next release, the method is found to be useful, so it's called from three places. In fact, it's called from two different code paths in one of the places. Does MyMethodError1 mean the same thing now as it used to? I say that it doesn't.

Only by taking into account the circumstances of the calls, as determined by the call stack, can you determine the meaning of the particular exception. An error code does not help with that.